# Epsilon Delta as x approaches a variable

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to solve the following epsilon delta problem:

Limit of $(x-2)^2$ as $x$ approaches $b$.

I can find $(x+b-4)(x-b) < \epsilon$, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

$|(x+b-4)(x-b)| \leq (|x-b|+|2b-4|)|x-b| <(\delta+|2b-4|)\delta <\epsilon $ if $\delta <1$ and $\delta <\frac {\epsilon} {(1+|2b-4|)}$.

Comment: I do not follow the inequality $|(x+b-4)(x-b)|\leqslant (|x-b| + |2b-4|)|x-b|$. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Write $x+b-4$ as $(x-b )+(2b-4)$. @Math1000

Comment: Very clever, +1.

Comment: This is what I had originally got, but when I tried to do the "proof" part, I wasn't able to turn (1+|2b-4|)|x-b| into |(x-2)^2 - (b-2)^2|